# Is there a way to merge 2 rows of a df into 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that has plenty of row pairs that need to be condensed into 1. Column B identifies the pairs. All column values except one are identical. Is there a way to accomplish this in pandas?

Existing df:

```
A B C D E
x c v 2 w
x c v 2 r
```

Desired Output:

```
A B C D E
x c v 2 w,r
```

Comment: Is it _always_ columns A - D that are used to identify the pairs and always column E that should end up with the adjusted (if a pair is present) value?

Comment: I have 1 column that can identify the pairs in the real data set. Let us assume it is column B in this case.

Comment: Could you make an [edit] to make that more clear? What if the column has more than a pair... and what about the other columns... would you still only want to end up with a single row per value in column B?

Comment: Yup that is correct, for each unique column B value, there can only be a maximum of 2 rows of data. The other columns ( all except E are identical) remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit unintuitive to read but works:

```
df2 = (
    df.groupby('B', as_index=False)
    .agg({**dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'first'), 'E': ','.join})
)
```

What we're doing here is grouping by column B and indicating that we want the first value occurring for each value of B across all columns, but then we're also over-riding what we want for the column E for aggregation to take place to join E's values sharing identical columns with B with a comma.

Hence you get:

```
   A  B  C  D    E
0  x  c  v  2  w,r
```

This doesn't make assumptions about data types and leave columns alone that aren't strings but of course will error out if your E column contains non string values (or types that can't logically support it).

Comment: this looks neat but does not work for me; complaining about `ValueError: cannot insert B, already exists`. Works if I remove 'B' from the agg dict

Comment: Did you copy/paste exactly as is and what version of pandas are you using @piterbarg

Comment: I am using version 0.25.3

Comment: well I had to modify it as the parentheses are not balanced (remove the first opening one). pandas v 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=0)
```

To use specific cols

```
df = df[['A','B']] ....
```